# Using a for-loop to reference each item in a list (instead of just the last item)

Tags: python

I do not understand how to reference each item in a list as opposed to just the last item when using a for-loop. Here is a simple program where I want to print a n-`*`'s on a line where n is each number in the `stars` list. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]

    for i in stars:
        char = "*" * i

    return char

print histogram()
```

The output of this code is only `***` (the last number in `stars`). How can I get it to print out the stars for each number? Please use the simplest syntax and explanation possible.

Comment: Please clarify the wanted output. My guess is that you want to do outside of the loop - char = "" and inside the loop - char += "*" * i

Comment: 3 lines output for above, first with 10 *, second with 2 and third with 3

Answer (score 4):

As it is, your function only returns the last value which was assigned to 'char' - this value will be a single string consisting of stars. What you would like to do, is create a list of the successive values that 'char' takes at each iteration of the loop:

```
def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]
    characters = []

    for i in stars  :
        cur_stars = "*" * i 
        characters.append( cur_stars )
        print cur_stars

    return characters

>>> stars = histogram()
**********
**
***
```

The above will print out the stars, line by line, and will store the list as the variable, 'stars'.

A faster/cleaner way to do the same thing is a list comprehension (a [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) structure), which creates your list on the fly:

```
def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]
    return [ "*" * i  for i in stars ]

>>> histogram()
['**********', '**', '***']

>>> print('\n'.join( histogram() ))
**********
**
***
```

Comment: apologies, i wanted them listed one under the other?

Comment: @johndoe12345 The point of this is that you can return a list, which is similar to an array. You then have to print that list (say `print('\n'.join(histogram()))`) to get them the way you want.

Comment: @johndoe12345 - edited accordingly, but check out Two-Bit Alchemist's comment as well.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - incorporated your suggestion below the list comprehension variant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for each item in the `stars`, you are reassigning `char`. Therefore, by the time that `histogram()` returns, char is equal to `"*" * stars[-1]` (the last item in the list). The simplest way to rectify this is to just print `char` for each element in `stars` and not return anything.

```
def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]
    for i in stars:
        char = "*" * i
        print char

histogram()
```

> `**********`
>   `**`
>   `***`

If you would like to instead return the output from histogram, you could add to `char` instead of assigning it to a new value. To do this, we set `char` to be an empty string (`''`) outside of the for-loop, and then inside the for-loop we use `char +=` (which is equivalent to `char = char +`) to add to `char`. The `'\n'` is to add a newline between each item in `stars` (without it, all of the stars would be on one line in the output).

```
def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]
    char = ''
    for i in stars:
        char += "*" * i + '\n'
    return char

print histogram()
```

A much more concise way of writing the above is:

```
def histogram():
    stars = [10,2,3]
    return '\n'.join('*' * i for i in stars)

print histogram()
```

Comment: why is char empty above ? also can you explain this line please char += "*" * i + '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
def histogram(li):
    rtr=[]
    for n in li:
        rtr.append('*'*n)

    return rtr
```

Then you can do something like:

```
stars=[10,2,3]
for t in zip(stars, histogram(stars)):
    print('{:4d} {}'.format(*t))
```

Prints:

```
  10 **********
   2 **
   3 ***
```

Comment: I think you meant to return `rtr` not `rtf` but other than this I do not understand the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def histogram():

    stars = [10,2,3]
    stars_str = ""
    for i in stars  :
        stars_str += "*" * i + '\n'

    return stars_str.strip()


print histogram ()
```